How to put a Firefox icon in favorites to replace the NON-REMOVABLE blank space that is there right now (launches and tool tip)?
I have lost the icon (there is a spot for it and that blank outline still launches Firefox) for Firefox in the bar (Favorites) at the bottom of Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS with Gnome. I also don't have a Firefox icon showing for the menu that pops up when you click the 9 dot icon in the lower right. I also cannot right click and "Remove from Favorites". The blank spot "occupied" by Firefox remains.
I have uninstalled Firefox via sudo apt and re-installed it and no change.

$ apt policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 133.0~build2
  Candidate: 133.0~build2
  Version table:
     1:1snap1-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 133.0~build2 1000
       1000 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     132.0.2~build2 1000
       1000 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     132.0.1~build2 1000
       1000 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages


This question is similar to: How can I create launchers on my desktop? and How do I add a custom launcher?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The fact that you cannot remove icons from the DASH is significant. (All or just Firefox?) Being a snap the desktop file (which points to the actual icon) is located at  '/var/lib/snapd/desktop' file called firefox.desktop. See if there are duplicates or other anomolies in this directory.  If you look in the file it points at the actual icon which you can check is present.

@david I just tried removing all the Favorites and they all went away including the blank one for Firefox ??  In /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications there is no firefox.desktop. I guess I need to create one. It is odd that uninstalling and re-installing the program does not do that.

@Scooter Sorry, you have an 'apt' not a 'snap' package installed.  So you should be looking for the desktop file in  '/usr/share/applications/' and/or  '$HOME/.local/share/applications/' I think the local overrides the general.  So try the same with this as I wrote in last comment.

@david I have a firefox.desktop file in /usr/share/applications . It has this line: "Icon=firefox" . I don't find anything with a find-search for 'firefox*' except two .desktop files.

The icons are in '/usr/share/icons/[hicolor | HighContrast]/[32x32 | 128x128 | 64x64 | 48x48 | 16x16 | 256x256 | 22x22 | 24x24]/apps/firefox.png' See if you have the same with the following search: 'find /usr/share -name firefox.png -print'  If you find one then try and put the complete path of that one into the desktop file.  If you don't find any you will need to add these somehow.

@david Thanks for all your replies I had icons in all those subdirectories and added the full path to one in the firefox.desktop (and copied it and pasted it into ls to verify it was a correct string) and still I only get a blank space where the icon should be but everything works otherwise. It seems that Linux needs a little more robustness here. Error messages should be happening. Uninstall/reinstall should fix it. Just seems like it this shouldn't happen this way in 2024.
